# PHP / MySQL - Create variable with name out of table content?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a variable in PHP which name is equal to an entry in a MySQL Table.

I have 4 tables. In each of these tables is a column named "release". In every row the entry in release can be different, but in general more than 10 rows have the same entry in release.
My goal is to count the quantity of every existent "release" in each table and if more tables have the same release i want to sum the quantities.

For example:

Table 1 has 20 releases called "releaseAX" and 12 releases called "releaseBX"
Table 2 has 14 releases called "releaseBX" and 10 releases called "releaseCX"

In the end i want to have 3 automatically generated variables, called releaseAX, releaseBX and releaseCX. The values of them should be releaseAX=20, releaseBX=26 (12+14) and releaseCX=10.
(I don't know all the names of the releases in the beginning)

I already managed it to display the names of all releases in each table with the related quantity of entries for each release.

To get all the existent releases i use

```
$releasesSW = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT DISTINCT LK_Release FROM requirementspecificationsw');
```

To display them with their related number of entries i use

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($releasesSW))
{
echo "Releasename: " . "$row->LK_Release". "<br>" . " -- Number of entries: ";

$count = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(LK_Release) AS Numbeer FROM    
requirementspecificationsw WHERE LK_Release = '$row->LK_Release' ");
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count);
echo $data['Numbeer'];
echo "<br>";

}
```

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [dynamic variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) like so:

```
${(string)$row->LK_Release} = $data['Numbeer'];
```

Note the two `$`s, meaning the variable will be named whatever `$row->LK_Release` contains, and the `{}` syntax with `(string)` because you need to cast to a string.

You could then do:

```
echo $releaseAX;
```

or `$releaseBX`, `$releaseCX`, or whatever release name you wanted.

Comment: That sounds good so far. The problem is, that i don't know the names of all releases. I could have 10000 different releases and 6000 of them can occur in other tables... i try to get something to work with the dynamic variables you mentioned.

Comment: If i try $$row->LK_Release = $data['Numbeer']; i get an Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.  If i try var_dump it says its a string?!?! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain more what you *do* want as the end result? I am confused - I thought you wanted to create variables that had the name of whatever the release was.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I want to create variables that have the name of what the release is. If the variable is already existent, it doesn't have to be re-created. First i check if the variable is already existent with if(defined("$$row->LK_Release")){...} else{$$row->LK_Release = $data['Numbeer'];} .. I keep getting the mentioned error. Oddly enough i have no problems with echo $data['Numbeer'];

Comment: Can you try `${(string)$row->LK_Release} = $data['Numbeer'];`

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to store these release names as keys in an array, or you're going to get some REALLY weird bugs when you ever decide to name a release after a variable whose name is also used in other parts of the code.

```
$releases[$row->LK_release] = $data['Numbeer'];
```

As an added extra, you can iterate over all of them and get a definitive list of releases and their numbers:

```
foreach( $releases as $name => $amount ) {
  echo 'release: ' . $name . ' has ' . $amount . ' as value.';
}
```

Comment: I already managed to get my code to work as i wanted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just be careful if you use this code in any kind of production enviroment. If you ever have someone who names a release something like "count" or "data" or any other variable name that is already in use by the program itself , the whole application will crash. It's a very risky solution.

Comment: Okay, i will remember this. Right now i can't do anything critically wrong because i'm learing to code with php ;)